# How do you override styles for layout nested views?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-theme

I am attempting to override *TextAppearance.Medium* in a custom theme that is applied to my entire application with the appropriate entry in my application manifest. For some reason, the style I have specified is not applied to views nested within a ListView that I am populating using a custom layout and a SimpleAdapter. **The style is applied to TextView views that are not items bound to a ListView**.

Samples of the theme definition and custom layout are below.

To elucidate, I am **not** having problems populating the list with items utilizing the custom layout, my theme is **definitely** being applied throughout my application, and I am also aware that my list item layout could be optimized by using a RelativeLayout. I am simply looking for an answer as to why my list items are not being styled correctly.

*Am I misunderstanding the capabilities of theme inheritance, or are there additional list-specific styles that I need to inherit/override?*

**API Level 7 (Android 2.1)**

**Testing using HTC Evo 4G, and generic AVD device**

---

**Theme Definition**

```
<style name="Theme" parent="android:Theme.Light.NoTitleBar">
  <item name="android:textAppearanceMedium">@style/TextAppearance.Medium</item>
</style>

<style name="TextAppearance.Medium" parent="android:style/TextAppearance.Medium">
  <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/black</item>
</style>
```

**List Item Layout Definition**

```
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:orientation="horizontal" android:padding="10dp">
    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="TextView" android:id="@+id/jobItemDateDueTextView" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:gravity="center" android:textStyle="bold" android:layout_marginRight="15dp"></TextView>
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="TextView" android:id="@+id/jobItemHeaderTextView" android:maxLines="1" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"></TextView>
        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="TextView" android:id="@+id/jobItemContentTextView"></TextView>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please take notice of the "android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" line in the list item layout definition.

Comment: The `Context` used to inflate layouts is significant when working with themes. Which `Context` are you using in your adapter?

Comment: The context provided by `Activity.getApplicationContext()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Continuing the discussion from the comment thread above, the application `Context` will not carry the same theming information along with it that your `Activity` does. Use your `Activity` instance when you need a `Context` for generating UI elements.

Comment: Thank you! This was certainly the problem. You saved me countless more hours of confusion.

Comment: @adamp This is such a great answer it makes me wonder why did it have only one upvote before I added a second one. Great great great. Thank you, Thank you, thank you.